# fdr correction for omics data

Tags: multivariate-analysis, multiple-comparisons, false-discovery-rate

I have a experiment design with 2 factors and I have 850 genes from this experiment. I want to look at individual genes before i go to multivariate dimension reduction .

So I plan to fit a two way anova with interaction of two factors(I cannot do separate anova model for each gene) followed by a post hoc analysis . My question is whether i do fdr correction on each of the pvalues i get for my main and interaction effect for 850 genes or on pvalues obtained from post hoc analysis.